# Net Core Simple way to Access Inner Class members

Tags: c#

I declared a Nested Class, and I am trying to access the multiple inner members below with a dot. What is the easiest way to conduct this for multiple inner classes?
This came about when I copied JSON data, and ran Paste Special --> Paste JSON as classes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WeatherTest.Models
{
    public class OpenWeatherResponse 
    {
        public class Coord
        {
            public float lon { get; set; }
            public float lat { get; set; }
        }

        public class Main
        {
            public float temp { get; set; }
            public int pressure { get; set; }
            public int humidity { get; set; }
            public float temp_min { get; set; }
            public float temp_max { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

In another part of program, I receive error:
**OpenWeatherResponse.Main' does not contain a definition for 'temp'**

```
 OpenWeatherResponse rawWeather = new OpenWeatherResponse();
 Temp = rawWeather.Main.temp,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, unless your classes are `static` (don't use static here, based on your question yesterday using serialization), you can't access them as you expect.

The reason is that, although you have nested classes, you don't have relationships between the instances:

```
public class A
{
    public class B
    {
    }
}
```

B exists, but isn't referenced as a member of A.

Instead you need to reference B as a property of A:

```
public class A
{
    public B B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string C {get;set;}
}
```

I've taken the liberty of un-nesting the classes since it isn't really necessary. You can still do it if you want to, of course.

Now, when you create an instance of A, you'll be able to access B:

```
var val = new A();
val.B = new B();
val.B.C = "hello";
```

So to fix your code, you can change it to this:

```
public class OpenWeatherResponse 
{
    public Coord Coord { get; set; }
    public Main Main { get; set; }
}

public class Coord
{
    public float lon { get; set; }
    public float lat { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public float temp { get; set; }
    public int pressure { get; set; }
    public int humidity { get; set; }
    public float temp_min { get; set; }
    public float temp_max { get; set; }
}
```

Sorry I haven't explained this very well. Hopefully you get my meaning :-)

Comment: @CarSpeed I've added examples using the classes created by `paste special` and from my answer above [here](http://rextester.com/AXBXH39238).

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `Main` is a type and not an instance of an object. Yet you are trying to access instance members.

You can do one of two things:

Option A. Don't use instance members in Main. Use static members.

```
public class OpenWeatherResponse 
{
    public class Main
    {
        static public float temp { get; set; }
        static public int pressure { get; set; }
        static public int humidity { get; set; }
        static public float temp_min { get; set; }
        static public float temp_max { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Option B. Create a property that will hold an instance of `Main` and use that instead. To avoid symbol ambiguity, I've renamed the class to `MainClass` and exposed a property called `Main`:

```
public class OpenWeatherResponse 
{
    public class MainClass
    {
        public float temp { get; set; }
        public int pressure { get; set; }
        public int humidity { get; set; }
        public float temp_min { get; set; }
        public float temp_max { get; set; }
    }

    public MainClass Main { get; set; } = new MainClass();
}
```

Either of these solutions will allow this code to work as is:

```
OpenWeatherResponse rawWeather = new OpenWeatherResponse();
Temp = rawWeather.Main.temp,
```